# bypassing the index.php file

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

i have a wee bit of a problem.

I'm currently working on a website addition to a running site. now the current website is written in a random framework which i was not able to recognize, and because the addition is rather extensive i'm doing it from scratch using CodeIgniter.

now i added my files to the server under and leading file name of 'business.php'.
calling my page works well with 'www.mysite.com/business.php' but when i'm trying to call a controller with a CI call like 'www.site.co/business.php/myController' i get an error caused by the server default call to the index.php file first and that has another way of treating URIs.

can anyone please tell me what can i do to bypass the original file?

tnx for the time and help.

Comment: If you're trying to bypass CodeIgniter's front page, and I assume the front controller, you should probably just not use a framework at all.  The point of the front page is to handle all requests.  Instead, look at how you can incorporate your `business.php` to go through the front controller....or not use a framework at all.

Comment: i do need the front page, how ever i need it to be mines and not the main site's. i mean, i need my front page to be the business.php file and not the index one, there's more to it however, look @ my other response. tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok! :) after some long research i've found an answer.

what i've done was to move the business.php file into a dedicated folder along with the System and Application folders, once that's done i've created a second .htaccess file with the above given code and placed it in the same sub-folder.

and finally, instead of calling to 'mysite.com/business.php/myController' i need to call to 'site.com/business/business/php/myController'

that way BOTH sites work perfectly fine!

another thing though, i'd love it if some one could tell me what code to i need to use in the .htaccess file to change all my long URL to a nicer one, i've tried the common commands but they didn't work.

thank you all so very much for your tries.

Answer (score 5):

Create .htaccess file in your project root directory and paste this...

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Next go to "config/config.php"

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

change this to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

That's all...

Your URL :

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/index.php/my_controller/my_function/param1/param2
```

becomes

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/my_controller/my_function/param1/param2
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: ok now that helped! can you please explain why did that help? all it did was cancel the index.php in the URL didn't it? the server already had a .htaccess file which had the following script:

(i can't post code here, but it's quite different)
why by cancelling the .htaccess file it bypassed it completely?
cheers :)  ho and one last thing - this works even when the config is at it's default value

Comment: sorry for taking off the accepted but as it turns out this didn't help, it probably took the server few minutes the refresh properly because the main site is not working with that configuration. whatever button i press it leads back to the main page (although my addition is working perfectly fine now =/) the existing .htaccess code is:

RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|php)$

# 89.139.186.33 #
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the index.php page the simplest thing to do would remove it.

The next option is to set the default home/landing page via your .htaccess file. Using this file you can set the homepage to whatever you want.

The code will look something like this `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html site-down.php`

Change those files names to whatever best suits you and your default page to land on when people come to your site should change.

Comment: well i do need the index.php file, just not for my page.
the index file is the front page of the site and the business file is the front page of my addition to the site, therefore i need them both but not at the same time.
and i do need the default page to be the index page so the .htaccess landing thingy won't help me much unless i can make it case-sensitive. tnx hope i was clear enough this time

Comment: So you need the index.php file for codeigniter I imagine. Am I correct in saying this? But the page you want people to land on when they come to the site is the business.php file. So you need the index.php file for your use but you want the general public to see the business.php files when they come to the site. Is this correct? Because you can set the business.php file to be the general homepage for people to come to and then you can edit and work on the index.php file by simply going to http://mysite.com/index.php

Comment: you are precisely  180 degrees from my intentions :)
and i've already done what you're saying, the problem is when i go to mysite.com/business.php/controller i get and error for the server still goes through the index.php file which does not know what to do with the part after the first '/'